# Xamarin.UWP Unhandled Exception during launch

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, aspnetboilerplate

My objective is to extend an [existing Xamarin project](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Development-Guide-Xamarin) with **UWP**.

I have two shared projects  , X.**mobile.shared** and X.**application.shared** ,  so i added reference for the *Uwp* project to this two project.

After following the steps to add uwp from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/index), I have also installed all the Nuget packages available in these shared projects as it's noted  in the answer of [these issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192203/how-can-i-add-a-uwp-target-to-an-existing-xamarin-forms-project/41212716?noredirect=1#comment98099652_41212716) .

Now when I debug the UWP project, I don't get any error but an ***unhandled exception***, I tried to pin point the ligne that trigger that exception and I found that uncommenting this line:

```
 rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

Triggers the unhandled exception:

[image: unhandled exception]

The message contains,as you see in the image:

```
    Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

which means that there is a referencing to a null object !

What am I doing wrong ?

## Update

With a BreakPoint on the ligne triggering the error , i tried to see the value of the method is arguments , i found that *DeclaringMethod* called by *typeofMain()* is returning ["*SystemInvalidOpertaionException*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).
[image: SystemInvalidOperationException]

what that means ?

## Update 2

Getting the advice of @Martin Zikmund , i checked the Stack trace and i found that the problem occurs at :

```
  Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Core.Dependency.DependencyResolver.Resolve[T]()\r\n at Acme.PhoneBookDemo.App.OnStart()
```

back to that class, this is the code of OnStart() method:

```
 protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            SetInitialScreenForIos();
            await UserConfigurationManager.GetIfNeedsAsync();
        }

        await DependencyResolver.Resolve<INavigationService>().InitializeAsync();

        OnResume();
    }
```

the problem is triggred when the debugger arrive at this line:

```
 await DependencyResolver.Resolve<INavigationService>().InitializeAsync();
```

Comment: Is there a link to the source code of the Xamarin solution on GitHub?

Comment: it's a private Github project of aspnetzero, so you need to pay to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I got a response from [xamarin-docs 's github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/1616)  , telling that in order to extend your existing UWP project with UWP all the nuget packages you use in your solution should have a support  to UWP (not only the ones that exists in *.shared*).</s>

In my solution i have many packages that dosen't support UWP, example :

[ACRSupport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.Support/)  supports only android and ios

In conclusion, aspnetzero 's project can't be extended to use UWP.

## UPDATE OF ANSWER:

A co-worker in my organisation found a solution by coping the implementation of **.droid* project.

This answer is useful for **aspBoilerplate** user, in particular  **aspnetzero** user, who want to extend his project with ***UWP***.

This are the steps , to make it work :

1. First ,follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/index)
2. If you run you project after the first step , you may be surprised by an "*unhandled exception*=**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**", this happens because the Dependancy Injection Container(aka service locator) can't find the **registration** of your  uwp [***abpmodule***](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System), So :

   2.1. Define a Module for your add Uwp project  (Add>NewItem>PhoneBookDemoXamarinUwpModule.cs):

   ```
    using Abp.Modules;
    using Abp.Reflection.Extensions;

      namespace Acme.PhoneBookDemo
      {
          [DependsOn(typeof(PhoneBookDemoXamarinSharedModule))]
             public class PhoneBookDemoXamarinUwpModule : AbpModule
             {
               public override void Initialize()
               {     IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(PhoneBookDemoXamarinUwpModule).GetAssembly());
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   In the initialize method above we register dependencies , IocManager is used to register the module class.
3. in ***App.xaml.cs*** 's *OnLaunched()* method , add these lines :

   ```
   //rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

     ApplicationBootstrapper.InitializeIfNeeds<PhoneBookDemoXamarinUwpModule>();
         await StartUpApplicationAsync();

    //Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e); // requires the `e` parameter
   ```

   then add this methods:

   ```
    private async Task StartUpApplicationAsync()
    {
       await UserConfigurationManager.GetIfNeedsAsync();
     }

   private static void ConfigureFlurlHttp()
     {
       FlurlHttp.Configure(c =>
        {
           c.HttpClientFactory = new ModernHttpClientFactory();
        });

     }
   ```
4. Add these Nuget Packages to your Uwp Project:

   [Xamarin.forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms) (ensure it's the same version with your ***.Mobile.shared** project)

   [Win2D.uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp/)
5. Finally from your uwp project, add a reference to **Acme.PhoneBook.Mobile.shared** , **Acme.PhoneBook.Application.shared** & **Acme.PhoneBook.Application.Core**

And that is it , it would run for you , as it did to me

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception it occurs during `DependencyResolver.Resolve<T>` call. `DependencyResolver` is a [class in Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/DependencyResolver.cs) which acts as a "service locator".

I don't have access to the source code, but this means there is a service that requires a platform-specific implementation which is not provided in the UWP project.

Check the Stack Trace for the Exception and you should be able to see where the dependency was missing and then be able to tell what needs to be implemented.I suggest you should look especially in the `ViewModel` of the first view that is loaded as it seems the service is required there (app crashes immediately on launch).

For details on how Dependency injection works in Xamarin.Forms see the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection).

Comment: I followed the call stack , the lower method call that i can visualize is : *> System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll!System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContextBase.Invoker.Invoke() *.
In it's **$exception>StackTrace i get  this:
"   at Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Core.Dependency.DependencyResolver.Resolve[T]()\r\n   at Acme.PhoneBookDemo.App.OnStart()\r\n   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContextBase.Invoker.InvokeCore()"

Comment: That does not tell much unfortunately... I would suggest contacting aspnetzero support directly. They should be able to tell which services need to be implemented.It may also be that they are internal, part of the framework, in which case it would require them to implement.