# Nuget Packages , Xamarin and UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Failing to extend my existing project with **UWP** , i search for reason why certain existing  projects can't be extended with **UWP**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192203/how-can-i-add-a-uwp-target-to-an-existing-xamarin-forms-project/41212716?noredirect=1#comment98099652_41212716) i get an answer that all the nuget packages of ***X.shared*** project should be the same(with the same version) in the UWP project.

However , even after doing that the project failed to start , so i asked in the 
[xamarin-docs github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/1616) and they tell me that the cause is a nuget package  supported only in Ios and Android.

So my question is :

Should all the nuget packages be the same for ***.ios** ***.droid, **.\shared** and ***.uwp** ?

And what if i have other projects(not xamarin projects) in my solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand the architecture of Xamarin and it is hard to answer in one paragraph, further reading of documentation instead of your constant asking of basically the same question on different places (please note that on the github you where warned that it was not the place to ask such a question) is highly advised.

But I'll try to answer. The package may use (or even need to use) native APIs to achieve some functionalities. Those native APIs are available only on one platform and such code is useless on another platform. So the package author in that case must write the separate implementation for each platform that he wants to support. He may cover just one platform or two or three, it is up to the package author. If the platform is not supported by the package and contains the native APIs, there is almost nothing that you can do aside to write your own implementation of the package for that. Even if you succeed in installing it won't work.